# SQL Select Statement where between two lists

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2012, coldfusion

I am trying to perform a select statement:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM ACCOUNT_GROUPS 
WHERE account_id = '1' 
  AND admin_user = '0' 
  AND active = '1' 
  AND uname IN (<cfqueryparam value="#send_to_var#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="yes" />) 
  AND uname != ''
```

If `uname` is a single var like abc1 it works fine. But now we need to search more....

So `uname` now has a potential list like "abc1,abc2,abc3,abc4"

AND now `#send_to_var#` could also contain more than one var like "abc3,efd6,asc9"

So I've tried `CONTAINS` and other SQL techniques but keep running into issues.

Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Comment: There are numerous articles on "String Split" you can search for to get an answer to this question.

Comment: Sounds like a normalization issue.

Comment: I am certainly going to search under that. Thanks!

Comment: But as I research this we have MS-SQL 2012. Is string split available in 2012 or only 2016 and up? Thanks

Comment: Hmm, you're sure your code is not working?  It looks perfectly fine to me the way it's coded in the question.  The only time I've had an issue with using an `IN` clause in CF where it worked with a single value but failed with a list of values was when I forgot to use the `list="yes"` option which you clearly have.

Comment: @user12031119 - It is because they are storing a list of multiple values in the "uname" column :-( Problems like this are one of the reasons why that is not recommended! Scott, the better approach is normalize. Store uname values in separate rows - not in a single column!

Comment: In the normalizing approach, they can create a new table `ACCOUNT_GROUPS_XREF` to store the normalized data, then create a View named `ACCOUNT_GROUPS` that returns the normalized data in the current table's format. Then you drop / rename the existing table and the current queries continue working against the view without needed to be refactored.

Comment: SQL 2012 will severely limit what you can do with regards to splitting strings. Also, SQL2012 is EOL, so it might be time to look at a potential upgrade. Anyway, this is doable, but involved. I'll write up an answer.  Also, how many rows are we working with? And how long can we expect `uname` to get? Lastly, are `admin_user` and `active` boolean values / bit datatypes, or are they actually stored as strings '0' and '1'?

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 there is a `STRING_SPLIT` function which will break up that `uname` column into a table which you can search with your list cfqueryparm. Your query will look something like:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM ACCOUNT_GROUPS 
WHERE account_id = '1' 
  AND admin_user = '0' 
  AND active = '1' 
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT (uname,',') 
    WHERE VALUE IN (<cfqueryparam value="#send_to_var#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="yes" />) 
  AND uname != ''
```

The performance could be awful - this is considered bad data design for a reason. If your SQL Server doesn't support STRING_SPLIT there are other solutions, ranging from bad to worse. Edit your question to post your SQL Server version.

Comment: I bet the `AND uname != ''` doesn't do anything

Comment: Putting the string_split list into a derived table sub-query and doing a join to that allows it to hit an index or be optimized into a sort merge join.  I try to avoid IN, good set math but bad query!  EXISTS is good for indexed co-related sub-queries, not this.

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett Let me make sure I understand. They may be an index on `uname` but because we are using `STRING_SPLIT` , that index cannot help.

Comment: Never mind. I see they are storing lists :-O Yipes! Agreed this is a bad db design, and should be normalized!

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett actually SQL Server will transform EXISTS optimally in the query plan. It's probably going to look like a literal comparison, and it will cut out on the first match. You'll still have to pay pay pay for the sub-optimal data design in the queried table.

Comment: Sadly I see the OP is stuck with SQL 2012. @DaleK can you create functions in your database?

Comment: Part of the fun is finding out how much help your RDBMS will give you in optimizing your query, but my motto is, you should have a good plan if you expect it to have a good plan!  If you plan and code for a sort-merge sort of join, you might get one or something like!  Having to brute force compare every value in some bucket of values for every row is a bad plan!  I worked on a GreenPlum DB with no indexes, just day partitions, so we had to rewrite every query for sort merge, which, with a herd of CPUs and scads of RAM, worked quite well!

Answer (score 2):

As others have already explained why, this looks like nasty DB design. But if you are really forced to persist with it, and you do not have `STRING_SPLIT` support, then a horrible hack would be:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM ACCOUNT_GROUPS 
WHERE account_id = '1' 
  AND admin_user = '0' 
  AND active = '1' 
  AND (1=0 <cfloop list="#send_to_var#" index="thisItem"> OR ','+uname+',' LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%,#thisItem#,%" /> </cfloop>)
  AND uname != ''
```

This assumes from the example data in your question, that your list delimiter is `,` without whitespace, and that there are no unescaped `,` characters allowed in the values stored in that list.

If the table is large then the leading wildcard will make this slow. But that's the least of your worries compared to the data design. Preferably plead with whoever is in charge for the time to overhaul that!

Comment: @Scott ... and that is a lof "ifs". Any one of those things goes wrong and the query fails to find a match. As everyone keeps saying, there are many reasons why storing lists is very brittle and slow, and should be avoided whenever possible

Comment: Surrounding `thisItem` with commas eliminate the first and last items of the list from contention.

Comment: My comment pertains to the answer by @SevRoberts.

Comment: Dan - The trick works by appending appending a comma to the `uname` values as well. So it always finds the value, regardless of whether it's the first, middle, last or only element in the list.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6eb12b7d00cfe7458bdba3f46bbf90b2

Comment: ... though as Sev said, it's a hack, and unlikely to perform poorly with large tables.

Comment: sql 2012 with Cold Fusion...use the cfloop. This at least puts the work into the app - but effectively runs the query for every element of the list.

Comment: @SOS thanks for understanding the leading+trailing `','` trick ;-)  And yes that's a lot of ifs/assumptions - but I think if any of them are not true, then nothing else (including STRING_SPLIT) short of a DB schema redesign is going to work either!

Comment: Sev - True. Having used lists in the past, just pointing out to Scott the subtle ways it can byte you - as motivation reason to normalize :-)